# Amazon EC-2 balance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon EC2 small instance + EBS for already several days. I know - it costs money, but nothing has been charged from my credit card do far.

1. How can I see, how much did I own to Amazon?
2. When does Amazon charges money for using his services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check them at account->account activity

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary

amazon charges monthly.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon bill on a monthly basis for AWS services, usually around the end/beginning of the calendar month. You can see running-totals of your costs by clicking on 'My Account' and then looking at the usage page.